# Bilinear filter on Android using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

Here is my code.It runs well on PC/Windows,but jagged on Android 4.42 when I magnify the image.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif


varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform float u_width;    //width  of image
uniform float u_height;   //height of image


void main()
{
    float texelSizeX = 1.0/u_width;
    float texelSizeY = 1.0/u_height;

    //four pixels' color
    vec4 p0q0 = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);    
    vec4 p1q0 = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord + vec2(texelSizeX, 0));  
    vec4 p0q1 = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord + vec2(0, texelSizeY));  
    vec4 p1q1 = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord + vec2(texelSizeX , texelSizeY));


    //bilinear interpolation
    float a = fract(v_texCoord.s * u_width);
    float b = fract(v_texCoord.t * u_height);
    vec4 color_q0 = mix( p0q0, p1q0, a );
    vec4 color_q1 = mix( p0q1, p1q1, a );   

    vec4 color = mix( color_q0, color_q1, b); 
    gl_FragColor = v_fragmentColor * color;
}
```

I'm sorry that I cannot post pictures. I debug the code well with VS2012, and the image seems smooth.
But when I run the program on Android, the image is full of jag. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question: why are you doing bilinear filtering in your shader and not just using the built-in hardware bilinear filtering? I'm sure there's a good reason, but telling us that might help you avoid a lot of questions along the lines of "have you set your filtering mode appropriately?"

That being said, it's likely to be a precision problem. You probably want to round `v_texCoord` to the exact sampling site as I'd guess that you have `GL_NEAREST` filtering set, to disable the hardware bilinear filtering, but due to precision problems e.g. `v_texCoord + vec2(texelSizeX, 0)` is then sampling the same texel rather than the next one along when `v_texCoord` is close to 0, or possibly the sample taken at `v_texCoord` is the next texel along when it's close to 1, or something along those lines.

OpenGL considers the centre of a texel to be its location. So if you were in 1d you could do something like:

```
r_texCoord.x = v_texCoord.x - mod(v_texCoord.x, 1.0/u_width) + 0.5/u_width;
```

Or if you were happy to use integral texture coordinates rather than the normal OpenGL [0.0, 1.0) range then you could simplify slightly because `floor` (and indeed `ceil`) already knows how to move you to an integral boundary:

```
(floor(v_texCoord.x) + 0.5) / u_width
```

... both of which are dependent reads so performance will suffer quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, I set the filter `GL_NEAREST`.  In fact, I used a PNG image compression which have a palette and store index values in data area. That is to say, texture is actually stored index . I want to read RGBA values in shader through texcoord and palette, so that I cannot use the built-in hardware bilinear filtering. I will try your method.

Comment: Cool. That code for truncating to the centre of a texel was written extemporaneously and it's difficult to believe there's not a better solution but it should help indicate whether precision is the issue at least. I hope.